# Node Stream - Make sync to return array when stream is done.

Tags: node.js, stream

I wrote this function to extract a file list from a stream. It works, however the stream is async and the `files` array is returned before the stream is done. I don't really want to use a promise library...trying to keep the code light as possible. How can I return the `files` array after the stream is completed?

```
function fileList(source) {
    var files = [];
    source.pipe(through2.obj(function(obj, enc, next) {
        file = obj.history[0].split("/").pop();
        files.push(file);
        next();
    }));

    return files;
}
```

Comment: You can't make an async operation be synchronous.  Just can't be done in JS.  Make an async design for returning the value using a callback or promises or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a callback instead of returning a value from the function:

```
function fileList(source, callback) {
  var files = [];
  source.pipe(through2.obj(function(obj, enc, next) {
    file = obj.history[0].split("/").pop();
    files.push(file);
    next();
  }, function(flushcb) {
    flushcb();
    callback(null, files);
  }));
}

// ...

fileList(stream, function(err, files) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // use `files` here ...
});
```

Comment: Quick question,what does flushcb() do here,where is it defined?

Comment: That function is the same as [`_flush()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_transform_flush_callback) in streams2. It indicates that the stream's `end()` has been called.

Comment: I should clarify: I meant the second function is the `_flush()` equivalent. The actual call to `flushcb()` is just letting node know that you're done flushing any data we may have buffered internally for whatever reason (in this case we don't have such data, so we just call the callback immediately).